# what will be CNF form of this probabilistic grammar?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, chomsky-normal-form, cnf

If PCFG is like,

```
NP -> ADJ N [0.6]
NP -> N     [0.4]
N  -> cat   [0.2]
N  -> dog   [0.8]
```

What will be CNF form? Will it be the following?

```
NP -> ADJ NP [0.6]
NP -> cat    [0.08]
NP -> dog    [0.32]
```

or somethings else?

Comment: please anyone help me, please!!

Comment: though its a late answer but if my answer helped you, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NP -> ADJ NP [0.6]
NP -> cat    [0.08]
NP -> dog    [0.32]
```

Your answer is correct because you need to get the same probability for the result by applying both the original and the converted set of rules (in CNF).