# How can I convert PCFG in CNF for this grammar?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, cnf

Given the following probabilistic context-free grammar -

```
1.NP -> ADJ N [0.6]
2.NP -> N     [0.4] 
3.N  -> cat   [0.2] 
4.N  -> dog   [0.8]
```

what will be the CNF??

Comment: The word "Probabilistic" doesn't have any meaning in this context as you can grab any CFG and convert it to CNF (i.e. in your case you can create drop NP->N and replace it with rules NP-> cat, NP-> dog, and then you adjust your probabilities to 0.4x0.2, and 0.4x0.8). See this for CFG to CNF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Converting_a_grammar_to_Chomsky_normal_form

Comment: yes I did the same  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769119/what-will-be-cnf-form-of-this-probabilistic-grammar) but was a little bit confusion, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given PCFG in CNF is given below.

```
1.NP -> ADJ N [0.6]
2.NP -> cat   [0.08] 
3.NP -> dog   [0.32]
```

Because you need to get the same probability for the result by applying both the original and the converted set of rules (in CNF).

Answer (score 0):

Be careful! You need to add keep the original rules 3 and 4 with the same probabilities in order for rule 1 to be productive